# Any meaning for an incorrectly calculated improper integral?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

In my introductory calculus class we are looking at improper integrals. Specifically, ones that involve infinite discontinuities in the interval of integration. For example, the integral $$\int_{0}^{3} \frac{dx}{x-1} $$ is clearly improper since the numerator of $\frac{1}{x-1}$ is zero when $x=1$ and it is easy to see that it diverges to $-\infty$. However, I am interested if there is any meaning to the answer we obtain if we evaluate this integral incorrectly. By "incorrectly" I mean in this manner:
$$\int_{0}^{3} \frac{dx}{x-1} = \ln|x-1| \Big|_0^3 = \ln2-\ln1 = \ln2$$
Is there any meaning to this at all? It seems (at least to me) we cant give this any physical meaning but is there a more abstract way we can assign meaning to it or is this equivalent to asking if $2+2=3$ has any meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can assign a meaning to the improper integral in terms of its [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value#Formulation).  Then we write

$$\begin{align}
\text{PV}\left(\int_0^3\frac{1}{x-1}\,dx\right)&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\left(\int_0^{1-\epsilon}\frac{1}{x-1}\,dx+\int_{1+\epsilon}^3\frac{1}{x-1}\,dx\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\left(\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}\,dx+\int_{\epsilon}^2\frac{1}{x}\,dx\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}(\log(\epsilon)+\log(2)-\log(\epsilon))\\\\
&=\log(2)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Like OP I'm also interested in this topic. However, I can only find a definition of the Cauchy Principal Value rather than meaning/interpretation/use. Could you shed some light on the purpose of this value?

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai Thank you; much appreciative!  And yes, contour integration sometimes involves a principal value integration.

Comment: Pretty strange that was mentioned in an introductory calculus course.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai The Principal Value was not mentioned in my course but I was inspired to ask this question since my textbook gave this as an example of what **not** to do when integrating improper integerals.

Comment: @1830, aha, makes sense now!

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\mrm{P.V.}\int_{0}^{3}{\dd x \over x - 1} & =
\mrm{P.V.}\int_{-1}^{2}{\dd x \over x} =
\underbrace{\mrm{P.V.}\int_{-1}^{1}{\dd x \over x}}_{\ds{=\ 0}}\ +\
\underbrace{\int_{1}^{2}{\dd x \over x}}_{\ds{=\ \ln\pars{2}}} =
\bbx{\ds{\ln\pars{2}}}
\end{align}